# Minimal Equivalence Relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If H < G and G/H is not a group,

(a) is there a minimal equivalence relation ~ on G/H such that (G/H, ~) inherits a group structure from the natural surjection p: G --> (G/H)/~ ?

(b) if so, what is ker(p)?

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel must be normal in $G$ and contain $H$. $$ \bigcup_{H\le N\lhd G} N$$
is the smallest such normal group. Divide by it.

Comment: What does it mean to  divide by a group? (I'm sorry, I'm really struggling in my Abstract Algebra class.)